ERC starting grant to move back into academia
I wanted to get opinions on an issue that has been raised to me about applying for the ERC starting grant scheme.
After my 3 years postdoc at the University, last August I obtained a Senior Scientist job in a biotech company we collaborated with for a project. They asked me to lead a new unit on the targets we found during the collaboration.
I’d like to apply for the ERC starting grant this year with a public research institute in Europe as a host institution. Essentially apply for an ERC starting grant to move back into academia, capitalising on a recent Nature paper published as a result of my previous postdoc.
Some people I have asked about this have been raising concerns on how my current job in a company can be seen in the ERC application.
What do you think? Is this seen a bad move from a reviewer's point of view which has to judge my academic career the fact I left academia to join this biotech and now want to go back to open my research group? Will I start already with some points behind?

The ERC eligibility guidelines explicitly say that "Research must be conducted in a public or private research organisation (known as a host institution/HI)." I fail to see how a Senior Scientist position at a biotech would not fall under "private research organization".

I was mistaken, I meant an ERC for opening my group in a public university in Europe. I am just worried that my new job can be seen as an escape from academia and thus it will not be judged well by the committee. What do you think?

So you want to apply for an ERC starting grant to move back into academia? That changes matters. Please edit this into your question, or clarify if I misunderstood.

Edited, thanks! Any thoughts about it?

You need confirmation from your host institution that they will support your application and host you if the grant is approved, but if memory serves that is built into the process.
I do computer science rather than biotech, but honestly "I went into industry to lead a unit on the targets I found in my postdoc" sounds like something which strengthens an application rather than weakens it. Check with mentors in your area, but it might actually be a good idea to highlight your ability to move between academia and industry in your B1/B2. (Your letter writers should address this, too.)

@NeelKrishnaswami: that sounds very much like an answer. Want to post it as such?

Like I said, I'm a computer scientist, and do not know enough about what the cultural norms in biotech are for me to feel comfortable making it an answer.

I've reviewed multiple ERC starting grants in materials/surface science and chemistry. In every case, the proposals were highly competitive, with prospective faculty that had very strong backgrounds and academic pedigrees.
You will be judged on the strength of your background (not just one paper, but the body of work), the strength of your proposal, and if it looks like you will have a high likelihood of success. A Nature or Science paper on your CV looks good, but that will not carry you through all the way, especially as that is seen as your postdoctoral advisor's work, not yours.
If you have been actively involved in R&D and publishing in industry, it will look good. If you have not done so and wish to return to academia, you will be up against people who have been actively publishing numerous papers per year, including top shelf ones in Science, Nature, Cell, etc...
So it will not be explicitly held against you, but it is a highly competitive funding scheme, and those who are very active in the academic setting are likely to hit higher metrics for potential of further academic success.
Take that for what you will. You should definitely still apply, and focus on providing a strong proposal, one that is clearly forward thinking, and that can be achieved at the proposed institution; i.e. the institution has the right facilities and framework to support what you propose, so for example if you propose to study protein structure but the University lacks high end NMR or crystallography facilities then it's not a great fit.
